# C# Lambda expression with IComparer and Array.Sort (converting from Java to C#)

Tags: java, c#, lambda

I'm trying to convert my lambda expression that uses the `Comparator` interface from Java to C#. I got the  following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   '`System.Collections.IComparer`' because it is not a delegate type.

I tried to switch to `Comparison<T>`, but it doesn't work with my `Array.Sort` methods:

```
Array.Sort(Population, Population[0].Comparator);
Array.Sort(population, 0, population.Length, population[0].Comparator);
```

PregancyIndividual implements IGeneticIndividual interface.

```
public virtual IGeneticIndividual[] selectPopulation(IGeneticIndividual[] population)
    {
        IGeneticIndividual[] res = new IGeneticIndividual[population.Length];
        Array.Sort(population, 0, population.Length, population[0].Comparator);
```

Here is my Java code:

```
@Override
public Comparator getComparator() {
    Comparator<PregnancyIndividual> IndividualFitnessComparator
            = (PregnancyIndividual ind1, PregnancyIndividual ind2) -> {
                int res = 1;
                double fitness1 = ind1.getFitnessCalculator().calculateFitness(ind1);
                double fitness2 = ind2.getFitnessCalculator().calculateFitness(ind2);
                if (fitness1 > fitness2) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (fitness1 == fitness2) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return res;
            };
    return IndividualFitnessComparator;
}
```

`PregnancyIndividual` implementing my own interface :

```
public class PregnancyIndividual implements IGeneticIndividual
```

I am now trying to implement my code for C#:

```
public virtual IComparer Comparator
    {
       get
        {
            //<PregnancyIndividual>
            IComparer IndividualFitnessComparator = (PregnancyIndividual ind1, PregnancyIndividual ind2) =>
            {
                int res = 1;
                double fitness1 = ind1.FitnessCalculator.calculateFitness(ind1);
                double fitness2 = ind2.FitnessCalculator.calculateFitness(ind2);
                if (fitness1 > fitness2)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (fitness1 == fitness2)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                return res;
            };


            return IndividualFitnessComparator;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but it doesnt work with my Array.Sort methods" - what happens? ("It doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.) You should use `Comparison<T>`, at which point it should be fine... Also, you can make your method a *lot* simpler by returning `fitness2.CompareTo(fitness1)`.

Comment: I've deleted my answer to write a new one, just let me understand, you want to compare 2 PregnancyIndividual, right?

Comment: Yes, two PregnancyIndividual classes. PregnancyIndividual implements the interface IGeneticIndividual. I use that interface for my Array.Sort:  public virtual IGeneticIndividual[] selectPopulation(IGeneticIndividual[] population)
        {
            IGeneticIndividual[] res = new IGeneticIndividual[population.Length];
            Array.Sort(population, 0, population.Length, population[0].Comparator);

Comment: Please check my answer, it should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PregnancyIndividual class to implement Icomparer and implement Compare as bellow:

```
    class PregnancyIndividual : IComparer
    {
        int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
        {
            PregnancyIndividual ind1 = (PregnancyIndividual)a;
            PregnancyIndividual ind2 = (PregnancyIndividual)b;
            int res = 1;
            double fitness1 = ind1.FitnessCalculator.calculateFitness(ind1);
            double fitness2 = ind2.FitnessCalculator.calculateFitness(ind2);
            if (fitness1 > fitness2)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (fitness1 == fitness2)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return res;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: How can i use this with my `public virtual IComparer Comparator { get {` ? Like `IComparer IndividualFitnessComparator;
             IndividualFitnessComparator.Compare(PregnancyIndividual ind1,PregnancyIndividual ind2);

                return IndividualFitnessComparator;` ?

Comment: Why you need to return the IComparer? You don't really use it as is, you want to sort an array of PregnancyIndividual, that's the reason you need it to implement the IComparer interface.